# This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: variable definition must be either a string or a hash

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - when: always

variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  IMAGE_TAG: 1.1
  DEV_SERVER_HOST: 3.239.229.167


stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy


run_unit_test:
  image: node:17-alpine3.14
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
    - ec2
    - remote
  before_script:
    -  cd app
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
    - app/junit.xml
    reports:
     junit: app/junit.xml


build_image:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - ec2
    - shell
    - remote
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .

push_image:
  stage: build
  needs:
     - build_image
  tags:
    - ec2
    - shell
    - remote

  before_script:
   - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
   - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
    

deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - ec2
    - shell
    - remote
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY ubuntu@$DEV_SERVER_HOST "
      docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY &&
      docker run -d -p 3000:3000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

while deploying to dev server gitlab yaml parser is throwing is error:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: variable definition must be either a string or a hash

I dont know why im getting this error

Answer (score 4):

```
variables: 
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE 
  IMAGE_TAG: "1.1" 
  DEV_SERVER_HOST: "3.239.229.167"
```

try adding quotes to variable values

some references - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/22648